# How to rename node attributes

Tags: ruby, attributes, nokogiri

I am trying to make an XML API more friendly. Part of it is renaming names.
So far, I managed to rename the nodes to my liking, however, I can't figure out how to rename node attributes.

XML:

```
<result>
  <rowset name="characters" key="characterID" columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName">
    <row name="Sult Dizarra" characterID="93125548" corporationName="Dry Atomic Fusion" corporationID="98012663" allianceID="154104258" allianceName="Apocalypse Now." factionID="0" factionName=""/>
    <row name="Bingu Pondarra" characterID="93421113" corporationName="Realm of Echidna" corporationID="98349254" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName=""/>
    <row name="Janna 'Wabisuke' Cobb" characterID="93431793" corporationName="Super Sexy" corporationID="98383185" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName=""/>
  </rowset>
</result>

xml.traverse do |node|
  if node.kind_of?(Nokogiri::XML::Element)
    node.each do |child|
      child.keys.each do |key|
        key.name = rename_method(key.name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I went wrong somewhere here along the way. Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the problem? What is happening?

Comment: child.keys doesnt have keys. not sure what to use. its a Nokogiri::XML::Attr
Which is a pair of name + value i think, but well as said, i kinda get stuck there

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with your code we need code that demonstrates the problem, along with the minimal input and expected output. Your code doesn't demonstrate anything, your input could be much simpler, nor do you have the expected output.

Comment: Unless you own the API, I'd recommend not making the XML "more friendly". Rely on the API as is, so you don't have to retool if/when they make a change. And, if you own the API, I'd recommend changing it rather than rewriting the output, for the same reason.

Comment: The place to make XML friendly isn't in the XML.  It's in the class or classes you write to encapsulate that XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root><node foo="foo" /></root>')
node = doc.at('node')
node['bar'] = node['foo']
node.delete('foo')
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root>\n  <node bar=\"foo\"/>\n</root>\n"
```

The core of this:

```
node['bar'] = node['foo']
node.delete('foo')
```

can be simplified to:

```
node['bar'] = node.delete('foo')
```

This is all in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node). I'd suggest spending time reviewing it, as Node and [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) contain the majority of the methods used with Nokogiri.

Comment: But how do i do this for the whole document? I need to walk trough the whole file and put every attribute name through the renaming function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I missed that i should get the keys on the node and not the child.